# Using Android Gyroscope in Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

Hello I have found that Unity3D does not give support for gyroscope on Android and at the same time there are apps using it.
I would like to know if anyone has a plugin to make it work or has any idea of how to make this.
My plan is making the camera rotate at the same rate as the phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

there is no gyroscope in samsung android devices u can use accelerometer instead.
To use accelerometer use Input.acceleration.x / y / z whichever u need.

Comment: Galaxy Note 3 has gyroscope. SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope returns true. And don't forget to enable gyroscope Input.gyro.enabled = true;                And, optionally, set the update interval to it's highest value (0.0167f) Input.gyro.updateInterval = 0.0167f;

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GyroDroid](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/101279-GyroDroid-2.0-Access-each-and-every-sensor-on-Android-devices-RELASED) plugin.